# Is there a way to read data from a text file using prototypejs?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I am writing a test and would like for prototypejs to read from a text file and store variables. Is this possible and what am I doing wrong?

```
Selenium.prototype.doLoadData = function(dataFile) {

    new Ajax.Request('dataFile', {
      method:'get',
      onSuccess: function(data) {
        var lines = data.split("\n");
        lines.each(lines, function(i) {
            var line = lines[i].split(' = ');
            window[line[0]] = line[1];

            globalStoredVars[line[0]] = line[1];
            });
            }
    }
);
};
```

Comment: Tell us what does not work and we can tell you what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

PrototypeJS passes the AJAXTransport object to the success callback, not just the data. Try this

```
onSuccess: function(resp){
    var data = resp.responseText;
    //or if your response contains JSON
    //and the Content-Type: application/json header was sent in the response
    var data = resp.responseJSON;
}
```